# CSS only working inline with PHP API

Tags: php, html, css, api

For some reason my CSS is only working when inline. I'm somewhat new to web design and not really sure about how to track down why this is occurring. It's not like I can open the console to check for errors, so what kinds of things should I look for? I'm sorry I'm not being more specific, I'm just really not even sure what to do.

Say the url is "www.example.com/testing/3"

The page testing.php would load, call API.php and determine what to do when on page testing.php with vale 3. API.php would then call a function on testing.php to deal with whatever that function tells it to do. So basically it calls out, determines which function to handle the URL, then calls back in.

When I include the CSS in the head of testing.php it works. When I just have a link, it doesn't. All of the files are in the same folder and I'm developing on localhost, no files are admin-restricted: I'm the admin anyway so permission isn't an issue.

```
//test.css
P.special {
    color:green;
    border:solid red;
    margin-top:85px;
}
```

Head of testing.php

```
 <link a href="test.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
```

A function on testing.php

```
 function view_event($event_id){
    ?>
    <p class ="special">
    //stuff here
    </p>
    <?
}
```

Comment: Can we have some code please ?

Comment: make sure your CSS path is valid & accessible

Comment: I'm pretty sure you used a relative link when setting your href in your LINK tag. Make sure the URL begins with a / so say files/style.css would be changed to /files/style.css

Comment: http://www.webdevelopersnotes.com/design/relative_and_absolute_urls.php3 here is a good explanation of the difference between relative and absolute urls. The same concept would apply for hyperlinks and images as well. It's best to use absolute urls by starting with / so problems like this won't happen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<link a href="test.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
```

would need to be changed to:

```
<link a href="/test.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
```

Using relative URLs will not work when you traverse into other directories. Setting it to an absolute URL with / will allow it to work anywhere on site.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the generated page source in your browser and make sure the CSS link is valid and loads the intended CSS file.

Web Developer Tools built into your browser (or as plugins) are very helpful in debugging html, css and js. Get to know them well.